# jQuery .load and .resize doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a load and resize function with a scroll function that should display a fixed header on window scroll on screens above 992px.

On screens below 992px i use the same header staticly positioned, the problem is that the .load and .resize function is not working properly.

I want the function to be consistent like media queries are, i don't know if that is possible, i would be thankful if someone knows how to do it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fvudr2h/12/embedded/result)

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
      if($(window).width() > 992) {
        function header_fixed_scroll() {                          
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('.header-fixed').show();
          } else {
            $('.header-fixed').hide();
          }
        }
        $(document).ready( function () {
          header_fixed_scroll();
        $(window).on('scroll', header_fixed_scroll);
    });
   };
  });
```

```css
body {
  height:1500px;
}

.header-fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background:red;
  display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .header-fixed{
    position:static;
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="header-fixed"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why u r using js for this? You can do it with css only.
Position: fixed;

Comment: I don't want it to be position: fixed on screens below 992px

Comment: So use media queries for it: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

BTW, just try out using position: sticky

Comment: But i can't make the scroll function to not show using media queries

Comment: check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3fvudr2h/13/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code fix:

```js
function header_fixed_scroll() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('.header-fixed').show();
  } else {
    $('.header-fixed').hide();
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
      header_fixed_scroll();
    };
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

.header-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .header-fixed {
    position: static;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="header-fixed"></div>
</body>
```